# How to add CSS to new window with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I use this codes to get html element in order to print out my table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    function printPage(){
            var width = screen.width - 50;
            var tableData = '<table width="'+width+'" border="1">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';
            var data = '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;     
            myWindow=window.open('','','width=auto,height=auto');
            myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
            myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
            myWindow.screenX = 0;
            myWindow.screenY = 0;
            myWindow.document.write(data);
            myWindow.focus();
        };
</script>
```

But, I have a problem.

My CSS style doesn't appear in print preview.

What should I do to get my CSS elements in my HTML codes? NB: My CSS style using class to get style values.

Comment: which css style doesnt appear? where is jsfiddle? HTML ? css

Answer (score 4):

try adding a link to your css file.

```
function printPage(){
        var width = screen.width - 50;
        var tableData = '<table width="'+width+'" border="1">'+document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML+'</table>';

        var cssHead = '<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>'

        var data = cssHead + '<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>'+tableData;     
        myWindow=window.open('','','width=auto,height=auto');
        myWindow.innerWidth = screen.width;
        myWindow.innerHeight = screen.height;
        myWindow.screenX = 0;
        myWindow.screenY = 0;
        myWindow.document.write(data);
        myWindow.focus();
    };
```